# CORS blocked in MS Edge but works in All other browsers

Tags: cors

#### The setup:

- Website is attempting to download a file from S3 (could be any server with properly configured CORS policies)
- Attempting to download a file using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js): `download("https://s3url.com/path/you/do/not/need/to/no.jpeg")`
- Under the hood FileSaver.js is doing this:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.open('GET', url)
```

- Chrome and FF work fine.
- S3 CORS policy is wide open

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET",
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE",
            "HEAD"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

#### The Issue

In MS Edge* only, using [FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js), any attempt to save a resource in S3 fails with `blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

- Edge Version 90.0.818.56 (Official build)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured out a possible "why" for this and a workaround.

Workaround is to use use the [beta Edge release](https://www.microsoftedgeinsider.com/en-us/download/).

I THINK the requests are being blocked because the `Origin` request header is missing when you run a XMLHttpRequest in Edge.

I hope someone else finds this and can stop spinning their wheels!  Not that it's very helpful if you're hitting this in a client facing application.

More details might come from here: Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/314369/xmlhttprequest-getting-blocked-by-cors-policy-in-e.html?childToView=318134#comment-318134

I've also opened [an Issue with FileSaver.js](https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/issues/703) incase you got here in the same manner I did and want FileSaver to work.